# "Add Scaffolded Item" Disappears After Visual Studio 2013 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have been having issues with Visual Studio 2013 lately and one of them being how MVC 5 is handled in the IDE.  I'm fine with them moving the adding of areas and controllers to a new submenu, but after Update 2, that context-menu item disappeared.  Anyone else experiencing this?  I can't find "Add Scaffolded Item..." after Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

Comment: If you right click on your Controllers folder (for example), do you see "Add" > "New Scaffolded Item..." ? I see it in my 2013 Update 2 on an MVC 5.1 project.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled and it's there after the base install of Visual Studio 2013 Pro, but after the Update 2 install and a reboot.  That menu item is gone.

Comment: I would appreciate if you answer my question too: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567537/why-add-scaffold-does-not-appear-by-right-clicking-on-controllers-folder

Comment: @Kardo, try installing Update 5 and see if the scaffolding options return.  In my case, I was under a short time constraint, so I just formatted my machine and reinstalled, but the updates generally correct these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another YMMV answer, but I was able to get this working by modifying the Registry.  In particular:

`\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ExtensionManager` has several branches, but the two of interest are:
`EnabledExtensions` and `PendingDeletions`

I moved the string key:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Mvc.5.0,5.0
```

whose value is

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WEB\MVC\SCAFFOLDING\
```

From `PendingDeletions` to `EnabledExtensions`.